# Prime ideals in $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $\dim(R)=2$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, prime-ideals

Prime ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ were listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56916/what-do-prime-ideals-in-kx-y-look-like); they are:

**(i)** $(0)$.

**(ii)** $(f)$, where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial.

**(iii)** $(x-\lambda,y-\mu)$, where $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now let $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with $\dim(R)=2$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to find a somewhat similar list for the prime ideals in $R$?

If this question is too general, then let us concentrate on the following three special cases:

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with each two of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$; for example: $a=x^2,b=y^2,c=xy,d=x-y$.

**(1)** $R=\mathbb{C}[a,b]$.
In this case, if I am not wrong, $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$,
so the same result holds with $x,y$ replaced by $a,b$.

**(2)** $R=\mathbb{C}[a,b,c]$.

**(3)** $R=\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d]$.

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.

I have asked the above question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063403/prime-ideals-in-r-subseteq-mathbbcx-y-dimr-2).

**Edit:** Special cases answers are also welcome.

Comment: What is the algebraic properties of $R$?

Comment: $R$ could be any subring of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ having dimension two. For example, I am not assuming that $R$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions (=normal) or that the field of fractions of $R$ is $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$. However, if it is possible to answer my question in some special cases, it would be nice to know. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I am not assuming that $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is an integral extension or flat.